# Postfix header_checks leading whitespace in regex

Tags: regex, email-headers, postfix-mta

I am trying to PREPEND some dynamic data with postfix header_checks. Namely, my mailing software doesnt support List-unsubscribe feature, so I am trying to overcome that with prepending it with postfix header_checks

My regex is currently like this

```
/^To:(.*)$/   PREPEND List-Unsubscribe: https://www.example.com/unsubscribe.php?list=1&email=$1
```

However, when it gets rewritten, or rather added to email header that link becomes

```
https://www.example.com/unsubscribe.php?list=1&email= random@email.com
```

So, my question is basically how to remove that leading whitespace from regex above?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may actually *consume* the whitespace(s) with `\s*` (=zero or more whitespaces):

```
/^To:\s*(.*)$/
     ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oyvxGi/1).

If the email is just a chunk of non-whitespace characters after 0+ whitespaces, you may even use

```
/^To:\s*(\S+)/
```

where `\S+` matches one or more characters other than whitespace.

Comment: Damn, i completely forgot about that. It worked flawlessly, thanks Wiktor